# 2 uitableviews in 1 and make their heights change dynamically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to accomplish the following. I got 2 uitableviews in a single uitableviewcontroller and at the bottom of the view I have a button. As soon as I click on that button (width of table view) it moves (with animation) to the center of the screen. Now I want the second uitableview to move with it and the first one (was fullscreen before) to shrink. So that at the end I'd have 2 uitableview showing data at the same time.

Clicking again on that button would, you guessed it, move it to the bottom of the screen, hiding the second uitableview so that the first one is in fullscreen again.

Any hints/ideas/code how I could accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a `UITableViewController`. You need a `UIViewController`, throw in 2 `UITableView`s, make them `@property`s of the view controller, and handle their data source and delegate methods as normal.

Then when you press the button, you can change the frames of the two table views just as you change the frame of any `UIView`.

Comment: Ok now I got the animations working so that the second table is showing up and hiding and so on. But how do I get the data to show up in the table? I noticed that i.e. numberOfSectionsInTableView is not even called so I'm obviously missing sth.
PS: I did add UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> but no effect

Comment: got it :) I missed the dataSource = self; and delegate = self; in initialization of UIViewController.

Comment: just so you know, you can actually set the datasource and delegate up using storyboard. Ctrl-drag from tableview to controller (in the bar just below the view window) and you can set them up. =)